# How to share internet from raspberry pi to a router?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I used to share internet from my laptop to a router in which it can be shared to other computers and devices.  I tried to do the same in raspberry pi, but i can't share.

Comment: are you saying your laptop was an access point?  why not just configure your router to be one or get a router that is?

Comment: No. I tried this http://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet

Comment: But i cant do the same in raspberry pi @dwelch

Comment: right, an access point, you want the wifi to be an access point for other devices and route that traffic to the wired ethernet.  if you take that same usb wifi device and use it on the laptop in question it works?  not the laptops built in wifi, disable that, use the same wifi device on both raspberry pi and the laptop, then it becomes a software question, if different hardware then it may be a hardware question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, when you use Internet Connection Sharing, Your computer becomes a router and uses a second connection as the external network. I haven't done it in a while so can't elaborate more on it.

The Pi would be better for this though...

In order to setup a RPi as a router, you need to adjust the routing table. 
If your wifi0 device is the internet connection then your default gateway will be the IP address of the AP you're connected to.

You also need to setup your eth0 or wifi1 (if you have a second wireless device) to an address on another subnet.
If your upstream router is on the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet, your second device will need to be on something else. Your internal nic on the Pi would be on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet with a static IP of 192.168.1.1 and netmask of 255.255.255.0.
There are many options for subnetting but just using the /24 address space is easiest for starting out.

Your upstream connection will not know where traffic to the internal subnet is supposed to be sent so you need to use NAT on the RPi so the main router sees the traffic as coming from the RPi. Once the RPi recieves the traffic, it will know where to send it according to the routing table.
You'll want to use iptables for this. You'll want to look up nat and forward rules.

You will also need to setup a DHCP server on the Pi so it can assign dhcp addresses to the internal network.